# Website for Android: what to do with low devicePixelRatio devices: tablets, smartphones, etc.?

Tags: android, css, html, web

I'm struggling with this for a while now.

I did a responsive website for a client, but then it turns out that **his tablet (Panasonic FZ-A1) has 0.75 devicePixelRatio**, which means, that it sais it has 1024x768 pixels, but actually displays less.

While I find it difficult to understand, what is the point in creating devices which say they can display a webpage properly, when they obviously will fail at doing that, I'm trying hard to find the proper way to handle this.

> **Here is the problem:** 1px borders on elements randomly don't appear.
>   Obviously, they don't appear on screen, because of the 0.75 pixel
>   scale. My site is responsive, but the browser 'lies' about the screen size - it returns 1024x768, so media queries in CSS are working as if it would actually be that big.

The meta tag in the header `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.33" name="viewport"/>` shouldn't be the answer, because it does not affect what the browser sais about the screen size, so CSS responsivity will not work properly.

I can't find anything in 'Settings' regarding screen pixel ratio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even some explanation, why would anyone product a device with <1 screen pixel ratio.

---

Update:

In the native Android browser, there is a thing under 'Special' settings, which I just found, and it makes it work. It is called 'default scale', with 'far','normal' and 'close' options. Selecting 'close' fixes the problem. But then again, default browser in Android 4.03 does not support some of the html5 features, and it would be nice if we could find a more generic solutions.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem with the same device, did you come across anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with the exact same tablet, and this is what I did in the end.

I had tried to use media selectors for low-dpi screens, and do html { zoom: 120% } which looked pretty good but was still missing a few pixels off inputs.

In the end I did this, which works great, basically it ends up setting the width of the viewport to 1024 which is the actual native resolution of those toughpads.

Note I still did user-scaleable=no as soon I think it's going to help prevent the click delay on mobile devices.

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Try and show the page nicer if we have a low dpi screen
    if(window.devicePixelRatio < 1.0) {
        var newWidth = Math.floor(screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio);
        var viewportContent = "user-scalable=no, width=" + newWidth;
        document.getElementById('viewport').setAttribute('content', viewportContent);

    }
</script>
```

I just wish I didn't have to use javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

We did exactly the same thing as Wizzard mentioned, but with a static approach since we needed our solution to work with the the above mentioned device only.

We used the meta tag

```
<meta content="width=640px, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
```

This forces the device to display your website in 640px width. The solution I accepted  her does the same thing, but with javascript detecting if the device's display ratio is actually smaller than 1, so kudos to Wizzard, and thanks for everyone's input.